# ef core select records from tableA with matching fields in tableB

Tags: entity-framework, linq, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to translate a query from raw sql to linq statement in EF Core 2

Query is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE FieldA = ConditionA
AND FieldB IN (SELECT FieldC FROM TableB WHERE FieldD = ConditionB)
```

FieldA and FieldB are from TableA, FieldC and FieldD are from TableB

I need all fields from TableA and none from TableB returned, so it should be something like

```
return Context.TableA
    .Where(x => x.FieldA == ConditionA)
    .[ some code here ]
    .ToList()
```

my current solution is to get two distinct result sets and join them in code, something like this

```
var listA = Context.TableA
    .Where(x => x.FieldA == ConditionA).ToList();
var listB = Context.TableB
    .Where(x => x.FieldD == ConditionB).Select(x => x.FieldC).ToList();
listA.RemoveAll(x => !listB.Contains(x.FieldB);
return listA;
```

i hope it works, i still have to run tests on it, but i'm looking for a better solution (if anything exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Contains` function in query like this :

```
var ids = Context.TableB
     .Where(p => p.FieldD == conditionD)
     .Select(p => p.FieldC);
var result = Context.TableA
     .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.FieldB))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: you may even avoid the first `ToList()` to emit only one query to the db server.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple join that needs to be applied -

```
var result = (from a in Context.TableA.Where(x => x.FieldA == ConditionA )
         join b in Context.TableB.Where(x => x.FieldD == ConditionB) on a.FieldB equals b.FieldC
         select new {a}
         ).ToList();
```